# How to store Chinese characters in variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get a cell value in a variable.

This cell value has Chinese characters in it.

When I try to get the cell value, I get '????' instead.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you intend to do with the characters? I have the same case and I am not (yet) experiencing any problems .

Comment: Actually i am designing macro to translate Chinese letters to english.

Comment: With that I admit that I cannot help. What I only do with the characters is get them from the sheet, pass them to a control (textbox/combobox) and if  there are changes (or not), write them back to the sheet. OT: So you are creating a dictionary-like function?

Comment: Unicode is limited to 255 characters, so everything above, like chinese letters are represented as `?`. You can store them in vars and print them into other cell without any problems. You may want to use `AscW()` and `ChrW()`  when working with chinese characters.

Comment: @Romcel, how to get characters and pass to control? can you please provide me code. It will helpful to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a valid answer, just to show the OP how I deal with non-English characters.

**1)** with a sample data like this.

[image]

**2)** create a userform with

*1.* ListBox defaultname = ListBox1

*2.* TextBox defaultname = TextBox1

*3.* CommandButton defaultname = CommandButton1

[image]

Paste this code

```
Option Explicit
Dim rCell As Range

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
rCell.Cells(ListBox1.ListIndex + 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
Refresh_Values
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
  With ListBox1
    TextBox1.Value = .List(.ListIndex)
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Refresh_Values
End Sub

Sub Refresh_Values()
Dim a() As Variant
  Set rCell = Sheet1.Range("A1:A7")
  a() = rCell.Value
  ListBox1.List() = a()
End Sub
```

***1** if there are changes in the listbox. it will reflect in the textbox.

***2** if you click save it should reflect unto the sheet.

***3** it refreshes the values so that the change made with the value will reflect in the listbox.

Hope this will help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your great support.

Comment: you would see below for your reference.
https://www.di-mgt.com.au/howto-convert-vba-unicode-to-utf8.html